# Post form using check boxes does nothing

Tags: slim-lang

At this point I'm just trying to getting the input from the form.  When I hit submit it does nothing and show nothing in the terminal.  I'm using Slim with Sinatra.

My two routes are

```
post '/user_search' do
  puts params[:checkbox]
  #slim :user_search_results
  # commented because I just would like to see something in terminal.  
end     

get '/user_search_form' do
  slim :user_search_form
end
```

I've tried creating a class for search as well as a helper method.  None of those approaches have changed anything.

Finally here is the form.  Granted I have some other forms that work find.  Those use text fields, so maybe it is the checkboxes that are throwing things.

```
form method="POST" action="/user_search"
label for="mp3" mp3:
input type="checkbox" name="mp3" value="mp3"
label for="flac" flac:
input type="checkbox" name="flac" value="flac"
label for="ape" ape:
input type="checkbox" name="ape" value="ape"
label for="m4a" m4a:
input type="checkbox" name="m4a" value="m4a"
label for="jpg" jpg:
input type="checkbox" name="jpg" value="jpg"
label for="gif" gif:
input type="checkbox" name="gif" value="gif"
label for="png" png:
input type="checkbox" name="png" value="png"
input type="submit" value="Submit"
```

This is non database input.  Just want to grab the params for a search method.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it all came down to indenting all the lines below action method.  I also indented submit passed those above.  Weird thing is other forms I have, have no indentation at all.

Comment: Are you using partials? Then you indent the `yield` only. Other than that you can always look at the html code to see what's going on. Without indentation you will certainly not have valid forms.

Comment: Yes, I'm using partials.  Yield in the layout is indented already..  Are you saying no indentation at all if it's a partial?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. If you indent the yield/partial then your partial file doesn't need extra indents because it is already indented on the yield/partial level.